# Why can't use INSERT EXEC statement within a stored procedure called by another stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, exec, user-defined-functions

First I try to explain the circumstances.
I store the the filter expression in one column separated by line breaks. The base idea was this:

```
SELECT  
'SELECT ''' + REPLACE(topic_filter,CHAR(10),''' UNION ALL SELECT ''') + ''''
FROM dbo.topic_filter T
WHERE
  T.id = @id
FOR XML PATH('')
```

After this I simply execute this string to put the datas into a temp table.
My problem starts here.
The snippet is in a stored procedure and used by multiple stored procedures to generate the base source to fill.
Approach 1:
Call this sp from another SP to fill a temp table.
Result 1:
An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.
(If I call simply with exec dbo... style the code is working. I only get the error if I try to call within a stored procedure)

Approach 2:
I put the code above into a table values function.
Result 2:
Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT EXEC' within a function.
(The function itself don't compiled)

Thanks,
Péter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the meantime I managed to solve the problem (with help :) ). The solution is simple:

```
exec('insert into t2 ' + @str)
```

Where @str contains a select statement.
I don't know why but this way there is no error. The method I call the stored procedure:

```
SET @exec = 'exec dbo.trFilterTopic ''' + @id+ ''',null,null,1'
INSERT INTO #filtered
exec (@exec)
```

I hope I spare some time to other folks with this solution.
Bye,
Péter

Comment: This fixed my error "Transaction context in use by another session" going between linked servers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is an SQL Server restriction. You cannot have a nested `insert exec` (I'm not sure why).

If you go:

```
insert into t(value)
exec dbo.proc
```

, and inside `dbo.proc` you have

```
insert into t2(value2)
exec(@str)
```

, then it will not run.

Consider different ways of passing tables around, such as [temporary tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) or [table-valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx).

Comment: Hi GSerg, I do not understand how this affect the core problem. The part where the string converted to a table is still have to be on the bottom of the callstack. So simplify my question, how to put that string into a table and use the results in stored procedures above it?  Thanks, Péter

Comment: Just a guess, but to avoid an infinite loop.

Answer (score -1):

Functions on SQL Server have limitations,
they arenot procedures, you can't use dynamic SQL like  'EXECUTE STRING', 'INSERT EXEC'...